# Numpy arrays - matrix multiplying arrays but taking 1 - elements in certain columns in the second array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is it possible to multiply two matrices together, but taking 1-elements in a certain column? I am multiplying large numpy arrays and don't want to break the arrays apart into multiple instances because I am running out of memory.

For example:

```
a=np.array([[0.1, 0.2],[0.3, 0.4]])
b=np.array([[0.25],[0.4]])
c = np.matmul(a,b)
```

except 1-b used multiplication:

```
1-b=np.array([[0.75], [0.6]])
```

before the matrix multiplication, but doesn't save it into memory after the calculation is done

Comment: Could you add a small code example to illustrate exactly what you mean?

Comment: sorry, have included it now

Comment: please elaborate on _except b is transformed into_. What does it exactly mean? you are multiplying a into a totally different b than you define originally. What is the point of having the original b then?

Comment: using 1 -b for the multiplication

Comment: Isn't doing `a @ (1 - b)` what you want?

Comment: Yes but only for some columns of b, not the entire array of b.